# Cant use properties of instance while running job on Hangfire

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, hangfire, hangfire-autofac

I'm trying to use Hangfire as job scheduler.

I created class called `Check` that has some properties (non-static variables) and `Run` method.

when I trigger the `Run` method (using Hangfire framework) for specific instance of the class, the properties in the Run method are not initialized.

I understand that it is a behavior of the default `JobActivator` of Hangfire (when the `Run` method triggered, is create a new instance of `Check` and run the method using it).

For my understanding the solution is IoC Containers to force Hangfire use parameterized ctor. I tried to use Autofac but I am unable to get it work.

How can I send the parameters to the ctor while schedule the job?

example:

```
builder.RegisterType<Check>.AsSelf();
.
.
Check check = New Check(<Some Parameters for ctor>);
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<Check>("id", x => check.Run(), Cron.yearly);
.
.
.
class Check
{
     public int x, y, z; // for example

     public Check(int x, int y, int z) // ctor with parameters

     public Run()
     {
         // Here I'm trying to access properties of the instance
         // Like this.x but none of the them is initialized.
     }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `x.Run()` in the expression? The current code would not compile, unless you have omitted some code that would show otherwise.

Comment: Without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that clarifies your specific problem or additional details to highlight exactly what you need, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What constructors does the `Check` class have? What is missing from it when hangfire runs the method?

Comment: Ive edited the post with more specific code example of the logic that Im trying to implement.